# Disabling the small tab titles in terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

In the mac default terminal app you can set a name for each tab.

However, whenever processes run there's a smaller title that shows up at the side describing what process is running:

[image]

Note how next to "Connex" there's that smaller `server * make run` thing going on.

Now the problem is that smaller title sometimes covers up the actual title.

How do I change the settings for this? I don't really want the smaller one to show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Terminal Preferences → Profiles, choose your profile in use, then the ‘Tab’ tab and disable ‘Show activity indicator’.

[image]